# TO convert PPTX or PPT files into PDF in php

Tags: php, wordpress

Any library or API to convert PPTX or PPT files into PDF format in PHP OR any plugins in wordpress available for PPTX or PPT into PDF file conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `libreoffice` installed on a *nix system, you can run a command to convert the file into a pdf:

```
<?php
  shell_exec('libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/converts/ /tmp/phpNWUB82bdw8');
?>
```

Be sure to create the conversion output directory and sanitize all file paths if you are directly inserting them into the command to prevent command injection.

Comment: Will you please tell me without dependencies of software through PHP code or depend on any PHP libraries or API.

Comment: Quick google showed this: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf you can try appropriating the code to be deployed with your application instead of executing shell commands or importing other libraries.

Comment: This one will only work for HTML to PDF conversion not for PPTX file to PDF FILE :(

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for same thing without any use of third-party API. 
For this you need to install libreoffice and unoconv on your server/system.

**Note**: I am writing the steps for CentOS but you can google for alternate commands for other systems

**Here are the steps:**

1. First install libreoffice and unoconv on your system using the shell/terminal

   ```
   yum install libreoffice-headless unoconv
   ```
2. If unoconv is not found by yum, direct download from rpmfind.net and install it:

   ```
   rpm -ivh unoconv*
   ```
3. If unoconv requires libreoffice-writer / calc /etc, do this first :

   ```
   yum install libreoffice
   ```
4. Finally, restart the server :

   ```
   reboot
   ```
5. This is an example to convert PPT file to PDF you can replace  :

   ```
   unoconv -f pdf slide.pptx
   ```
6. if you want to run the command through PHP use: phpseclib

   ```
   $command = "unoconv -f pdf /home/username/public_html/slide.pptx";

   $ssh->exec($command);
   ```
7. Alternatively you can use libreoffice to do the conversion for you from the shell :

   ```
   libreoffice –headless –invisible –convert-to pdf sample.doc
   ```
8. After installation of libreoffice on your server you can use this [PHP Wrapper for LibreOffice](https://github.com/ncjoes/office-converter) to convert the files easily into pdf/html. I have tested it and it is working well.
9. Finally if you want to covert your pdf into jpg you can use [imagick class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php).

Credit and thanks to: [PDF DOCUMENT CONVERSION IN CENTOS 7 USING UNOCONV AND LIBREOFFICE](https://cikkim.wordpress.com/2015/10/17/pdf-document-conversion-in-centos-7-using-unoconv-and-libreoffice/)